# Integral of $(-1)^x$

Tags: calculus

> $f(x) = (-1)^x$

If $f(x) = a^x, F(x) = a^x/\ln(a)$

but we can't use this formula, since $\ln(x)$ takes only positive arguments. Does this function have a primitive function?

Comment: How do you define $(-1)^{\sqrt2}$?

Comment: How is it defined?

Comment: What is domain of the function? If you put $x=0.5$ then it will be Complex number

Comment: Even worse than $x=0.5$ is $x=1/3=2/6$...

Comment: Also, $\ln$ can be defined (and is quite freuqently so) on the complexes. Typically, $\ln(r) + i \theta$, where $r$ is the [modulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) and $\theta$ is the [argument](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html).

Answer (score 9):

The first question is how we *define*  $(-1)^x$ in the first place. For this we recall Euler: $$e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t).$$It follows that $-1=e^{i\pi}$, so a natural definition is $$f(x)=(-1)^x=e^{i\pi x}=\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x).$$Hence a primitive is given by $$F(x)=\frac 1{i\pi}f(x).$$

**Note** There are going to be complex numbers involved here, and any time you have complex numbers and logarithms things get complicated. It's also true for example that $-1=e^{-i\pi}$, so another reasonable definition would be $(-1)^x=e^{-i\pi x}$. (Yes, that really is different: In general $e^{i\pi x}\ne e^{-i\pi x}$, even though $e{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi}$.) This is why I said "*a* definition" above, instead of "*the* definition". In fact there are infinitely many equally sensible definitions here; the one above is the "principal value" of $(-1)^x$; it's sort of the default.